# excel count rows where column B OR C OR D is higher than X

Tags: excel, count, countif

There is a table:

excel table

[image]

And I need excel to count me rows that that at least one of the size measure are over 40. In other words:

> **COUNT** B.1994 **IF** length is > 40 **OR** width is > 40 **OR** height is > 40

And it should return in this case **3** rows.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUM(IF(MMULT(--($B$2:$D$5>40),{1;1;1})>0, 1, 0)*--($A$2:$A$5="B.1994"))`

> Ctrl-Shift-Enter (Array formula)

Edit: new requirement:

`=SUM(IF(MMULT(--($B$2:$D$5>40),{1;1;1})>1, 1, 0)*--($A$2:$A$5="B.1994"))`

The if condition tests if the matrix multiplication totals greater than 1. The original version tested if greater than 0.

Last Edit for requirement:

`=SUM(IF(($E$2:$E$5>5)+(MMULT(--($B$2:$D$5>85),{1;1;1})>0)+(MMULT(--($B$2:$D$5>40),{1;1;1})>1)+--($B$2:$B$5*$C$2:$C$5*$D$2:$D$5>3600), 1, 0)*--($A$2:$A$5="B.1994"))`

Comment: would there be a way to count rows if two or three of the variables are over 40 if only one we dont count

Comment: That is a brilliant piece of code you wrote there! But i would like to ask for a help once more.

Ideally I would need to:
Count rows if item weight exceeds 5kg (weight data is stored in E column) -- DONE
Count rows if item single side dimension exceeds 85cm -- DONE
Count rows if item two sides dimensions exceeds 40cm -- DONE
Count rows if item cubic volume exceeds 3600 -- **TBC**

And after all this I need to put all into one cell so it pulls a count of rows according to the IF statements above.

Would it be possible to do so?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work for me @MacroMarc Excel gives me an error that im entering too many arguments into the function. I have uploaded spreadsheet onto the gdrive so you can have a better image [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_yVmVXbyObVWFiTldhbmZ2RFk/view?usp=sharing)

I need this formula to appear on **CODES** sheet **E2** cell.

I really appreciate your help, Thank You!

Comment: Ive tested it, so it should be working. I see the formula on the sheet you have is not copied correctly from my formula: `(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD:AF>CODES!K3>1)` should be `(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD:AF>CODES!K3), {1;1;1})>1)`

Comment: Got it working but not quiet as expected. The final formula i got is: **find a formula bellow**
And it is forcing me to type ranges into formula. This isnt ideal for me because every night i will be pasting data in **Data paste** sheet and every day volume of data could be ranging from hundreds to thousands. I have tried to do a workaround using indirect but it doesnt seem to work. Please find the link to the spreadsheet online [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_yVmVXbyObQW9zQ2F0UGh0RHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: **Final**
 `=SUM(IF(('Data paste'!AA2:AA5>CODES!$K$2)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$1),{1;1;1})>0)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$3),{1;1;1})>1)+--('Data paste'!AD2:AD5*'Data paste'!AE2:AE5*'Data paste'!AF2:AF5>CODES!$K$4), 1, 0)*--('Data paste'!Q2:Q5=CODES!C2))`

**INDIRECT**
`=SUM(IF((INDIRECT("'" &  $K$6 & "'!" & $K$7)>CODES!$K$2)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$1),{1;1;1})>0)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$3),{1;1;1})>1)+--('Data paste'!AD2:AD5*'Data paste'!AE2:AE5*'Data paste'!AF2:AF5>CODES!$K$4), 1, 0)*--('Data paste'!Q2:Q5=CODES!C2))`

Comment: Or you @MacroMarc would suggest simply changing formula range to AA2:AA999999 ? The reason why im asking is that I would like to cut calculation time as much as possible. As I understand if I leave range up to 999K rows down excel will go through every single row even if it is empty until reaches bottom? Or I could count how many records I got and tell excel where is it suppose to stop calculating. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM((A2:A5="B.1994")*(((B2:B5>40)+(C2:C5>40)+(D2:D5>40))>0))
```

press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(A2="B.1994",MAX(B2:D2)>40),1,0)
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell:

```
=SUM(E2:E5)
```

[image]

*(The key point is that if any of the elements in a row is greater than 40, then the MAX() of those elements must also be greater than 40)*

Answer (score -1):

```
=COUNTIFS(range1,critera1,range2,critera2)
```

The COUNTIFS function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met.

If your data starts in cell A1 it would look something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,">40",C2:C5,">40",D2:D5,">40")
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I think he wants to count if *any* of his 3 criteria are met, not if *all* of them are met.